# What can be done if a question that was closed by the review process is re-opened by a Gold Badge holder incorrectly?

Tags: discussion, privileges, dupehammer, vote-to-reopen, tag-badges

After reading through this existing question;

> *[Restrict Mjölnir privilege when voting to re-open a question that was close-voted by multiple users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333620/692942)*

Feel this needs some discussion, just had a situation where a Gold Badge holder has re-opened a clear duplicate question that had at least three possible dup targets.

Unfortunately, there are certain members of this community who want to work against the rest of us. Would prefer they use their powers for good rather than evil, what I mean is, if they see an obvious duplicate, hammer it before it has a chance to gain traction.

What I don't understand is now that the question is re-opened, after previously flagging it for closure as a duplicate I can no longer re-vote to close it. This means all the power is with the Gold Badge holder, which when misused, in my opinion, is a problem.

At the very least, shouldn't the close votes be reset allowing previous voters to re-flag for closure?

Comment: Remember to assume good faith; Mjolnir holders are trusted to exercise their judgement as they have demonstrated expertise in the tag.  They *can* get it wrong, but so can the five users who originally voted to close.

Comment: @fbueckert The question had been marked with three duplicate targets though.

Comment: Could you add a link to the question? Reopening a duplicate-closed question sounds a bit strange at first, but there might be a context we don't see here.

Comment: @BDL keep in my OP seems to be asking about policy here rather than the specific question that prompted this concern.

Comment: @BDL I didn't want to make this about "the question" but if you are really interested it's not hard to track down.

Comment: It's hard to keep this general when you're using arguments that make it specific to the question.

Comment: @fbueckert: Except his argument *isn't* specific to the question. It's just using the question as an example of the problem.

Comment: @NicolBolas "The question had been marked with three duplicate targets though."  That...seems awful specific to me.  I made a general comment, and got an argument that was specific to the question being used as an example.  No issues keeping it general, as long as it's actually general.

Comment: @fbueckert: And that was a *comment*, not in the question itself. Specifically, since his question asks about the question being unclosed *incorrectly*, replying with "what if they're right" is off-topic. The question *assumes* that they aren't right, even if, in the specific example, they might be.

Comment: @NicolBolas So...assuming good faith is now off-topic?  That seems unnecessarily pedantic and more splitting hairs than anything else.  That argument is also in the question; "...that had at least three possible dup targets."

Comment: @NicolBolas Should we really discuss if a gold badge holder should reopen a question that was correctly closed? The only answer would be: gold badge holders should only reopen if the questions should not be closed. What's the point to discuss here?

Comment: @BDL: It doesn't need to be a particularly long or involved discussion, but yes, what to do if someone makes a mistake should be discussed. The current answer adequately covers the bases. It corrects the misconceptions in the question, explains how the system works, and tells them what to do about it.

Comment: @Lankymart Consider this: the fact that there were three different duplicate targets signals that _the close voters didn't reach consensus_ on what the question was actually a duplicate of!

Comment: @duskwuff without going into specifics anyone of them would do or all three, to be honest there was more and it doesn't take a gold badge holder to know that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are concerned about the specific question that prompted this question, the appropriate response, in my opinion, is to ask in a subject-matter chatroom (if one exists and is active) or ask about it on here with the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and [specific-question](/questions/tagged/specific-question) tags, and also be sure to link to said meta post in a comment on the actual SO question so that relevant and interested stakeholders can weigh in.

Regarding misuse, it's hard to say this case constitutes misuse, IMHO; I took a look at the question that prompted this, and the gold badge user who reopened this question is one of the answerers on the dupe target. Not only is that the *opposite* path of standard misuse (e.g. a user closes questions as dupes of ones they've answered to drive traffic/votes to their own answers), but because OP is a SME *and* has an upvoted answer on the suggested dupe target, they're extra likely to know whether the question is a duplicate (e.g. "no, my code from the dupe target answer would not work for the situation asked about in this question").

> now that the question is re-opened, after previously flagging it for closure as a duplicate I can no longer re-vote to close it. This means all the power is with the Gold Badge holder

No, it means the gold badge holder has the privilege to cast a unilateral close or reopen vote (one time each) on questions that are duplicates, due to their score in at least one tag on said question. This score indicates they are a proven subject matter expert (SME), at least within the Stack Overflow system, as fbueckert commented.

Consider if five users, instead, had voted to reopen the question. Would you consider "all the power" being with those five people in a bad way, like you do the gold badge holder in this case? If not, why not?

> At the very least, shouldn't the close votes be reset allowing previous voters to re-flag for closure?

Close votes are a one-time deal; if the question changes state and gets closed, or gets reopened, the people who voted to close it or reopen it cannot do so again. You can only re-cast a close or reopen vote a second time if your vote ages away without the question getting closed/reopened during the vote's existence. This is by design, and changing it would allow for close/reopen wars, which I don't think anyone wants to deal with.

Comment: "a user closes questions as dupes of ones they've answered to drive traffic/votes to their own answers" this is not misuse. If a gold badge owner identified one of their questions to be very frequent, they should be closing their questions against it, like they would have done if it wasn't theirs.

Comment: @Braiam It's implied in the context of misuse that the dupe closures would be dubiously accurate, at best, in addition to the phrase "to drive traffic/votes to their own answers" serving as the reason for closure, which *is* misuse; you should close questions as dupes because they're dupes.

Comment: @TylerH about misuse, I meant in relation to not doing what would be obvious which is to close as a duplicate. In other words, they feel that marking stuff as duplicate takes away from their opportunity to answer the question, when in reality flagging the question would be the correct course IMO.

Comment: @Lankymart The question was already closed when the gold badge user reopened it, so I'm not sure what your argument is when you say "they should have flagged the question" for closure. And my response argues that it's obvious to *them* (the expert), that it's *not* a duplicate, so in fact reopening the question is the *right* thing to do and closing it as a duplicate is the *wrong* thing to do. And the gold badge user did not answer the question after reopening it, so that argument does not seem to hold water, either.

Comment: @TylerH but that's precisely why it should. To drive viewers towards the question that has answers. What you are describing is the system of duplicates working as it should, just that you cast mistrust into the user closing questions. What would be misuse, is closing questions that doesn't have resemblance between the issues being asked about.

Comment: @Braiam No, the critical reason here is what's important, and that's "because it is a duplicate". Closing something as a duplicate *to drive views to my answer* means, in English, that I want people to view my answer instead of any potential answers of the dupe question, period. Maybe there's just a language barrier here?

Comment: @TylerH I don’t think they truely believe that is doesn’t fit at least one of the duplicates listed if I’m honest.

Comment: @Lankymart Unfortunately only one question is listed as a duplicate target in the question at hand... so it's not super useful to continue referencing "three dupes" unless we can know what's going on. At any rate, it seems you are concerned with this one question in particular rather than a general policy about close votes, so I'd recommend asking a separate Meta question about that specific Q on Main.

Comment: @TylerH There was definitely three dup targets, I'm guessing they were removed when the question was closed by review.

Comment: @Lankymart If they were mentioned in auto-comments from close votes/flags, then they would've been removed after the question was closed, yes. Any of them that were above the threshold set by the system, IIRC, would be converted to target dupes in the closure banner. The only other way for the timeline/revision history to show them would be if a gold badge user or moderator edited the dupes list to include them.

Comment: @TylerH "potential answers of the dupe question" that's the whole point of closing as duplicate. Preventing the answers to be dispersed in many questions. When you close as duplicate a question, you also are preventing "potential answers of the dupe question", the fact that the target is your own post is irrelevant.

Comment: @TylerH well it has a *few* dup targets now...

Comment: @Braiam it's clear you don't really understand what I said. Put another way, the important point here of the *one edge-case interpretation of part of what I said* is *intent*, but that's really getting down into the roots of the weeds.

Comment: And you seems to only read your own words: **intent is irrelevant**. As long as the duplicates are actual duplicates, who closes or who owns the post is also irrelevant.