# How should we handle "weasel words", or unintentionally broad questions that aren't?

Tags: discussion, opinion-based, needs-more-focus

Related to [Is asking for solutions to a problem that has more than one possible solution too broad for SO?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402142/is-asking-for-solutions-to-a-problem-that-has-more-than-one-possible-solution-to) and [Please stop having opinions about things](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402905/please-stop-having-opinions-about-things), but meant as a more general question.

I think that sometimes people are too eager to close based on "[weasel words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weasel_word)". Yes, there is this hate for [Gimme teh codez](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308837/make-it-easier-to-close-job-shop-gimme-teh-codez-questions)-questions, which is justified: a question whose title and body combined contain no more than, for example, *"How to write a calculator in Go"* or *"I want to expose my database over a REST API, discuss"*, is not specific enough to answer with a couple of paragraphs and does not have one or a handful of definitive answers, and should therefore be closed until the asker adds some constraints.

However, usually <sup>[citation needed]</sup>, questions merely *containing* such language aren't actually that broad - the OP just doesn't know how to write their question without sounding overly dramatic or desperate. *"Is there any way to do the same?"* does not mean *"Please enumerate all possible ways to solve this problem"*, it means *"How to do X"*.

And "How to do X"-questions are exactly what this site is meant to answer, given a narrow enough context. *Every* question can ultimately be answered by *"Use this assembly listing to instruct your CPU to move some values"* (or [butterflies](https://xkcd.com/378/)), but that does not make every question too broad.

So can we please take a step back, and not jump straight to the close button when we read the words "any way", "opinion", "best practice", and so on, but perhaps help the (usually not natively English speaking) OP by merely editing out such terms that may make a question seem to have not enough focus?

Gimme teh answerz.

---

Just a couple of search results of closed questions that contain "is there any way" and are considered by some, but not me, to be not focused enough or otherwise off-topic, and as a bonus, something asking for opinions but answered with facts and references:

- [Your opinion on declaring constants inside methods…?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676849/your-opinion-on-declaring-constants-inside-methods) (deleted, 10K only)
- [Is there any way to post events to Google Analytics via server-side API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9503329/is-there-any-way-to-post-events-to-google-analytics-via-server-side-api) - a simple question with a simple answer: use this particular HTTP POST format, [link to docs]
- [How to create EditText with rounded corners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646415/how-to-create-edittext-with-rounded-corners) - a very common question in UI design, with very <strike>round</strike>straightforward answers
- [How to find out "The most popular repositories" on Github?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19855552/how-to-find-out-the-most-popular-repositories-on-github) - is asking how to use a specific feature of a Git hosting website, a tool used primarily by (millions of) developers, with two links as answers. This is just as on-topic as asking where to find a particular setting in your favorite IDE.
- [No matching client found for package name (Google Analytics) - multiple productFlavors & buildTypes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34990479/no-matching-client-found-for-package-name-google-analytics-multiple-productf) - how on earth is that asking for multiple things?

Counter-examples from that same search:

- [Database, Table and Column Naming Conventions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7662/database-table-and-column-naming-conventions) - definitely asking for opinions, answers are written from preferences, not references
- [Best practices for API versioning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389169/best-practices-for-api-versioning) - questionable at best, it comes down to the practicality of having a version number in an URI versus in a request header. Brings out REST purists, which is usually a recipe for opinionated posts.

Or, more interesting, newish, closed, upvoted questions:

- [What is the best way to create fallback for clamp()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63933097/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-fallback-for-clamp) - they're not asking for opinions, they're asking for the way with the most coverage in browser support
- [tf.divide() and tf.cast() will interrupt the gradient propagation of my program. Is there any way to solve this problem？](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64889770/tf-divide-and-tf-cast-will-interrupt-the-gradient-propagation-of-my-program) - how is this asking for multiple things?
- [PHP native levenshtein 100x faster than custom implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63687771/php-native-levenshtein-100x-faster-than-custom-implementation) - is asking one question, namely why a PHP version of a built-in function is way slower. The answer is *"because PHP is interpreted, and built-in functions are written in C"*
- [How to forecast monthly time series data with ARIMA or scikit-learn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63479612/how-to-forecast-monthly-time-series-data-with-arima-or-scikit-learn) - is machine learning not programming?
- [C# comparing strings ignoring both: whitespaces, CR etc and cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64872554/c-sharp-comparing-strings-ignoring-both-whitespaces-cr-etc-and-cases) - not sure what is unclear about "ignore whitespace and case in string comparison". The code they show does not solve their problem, but that's quite usual in questions.
- [Is there anyway to obfuscate a public JavaScript file in angular(not external libraries)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64862607/is-there-anyway-to-obfuscate-a-public-javascript-file-in-angularnot-external-li) - obfuscation is one problem, and they're asking for a built-in way without external dependencies.

And the list goes on and on. Note that many of those questions have factual, upvoted answers. Last but not least, one I recently answered:

- [HTTP conditional requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64681296/http-conditional-requests) - closed because it was perceived as being "about professional server or networking-related infrastructure administration"? Wat.jpeg?

To rehash, what I'm agitating against, is that "we" (close-voters) are expecting the OP to utilise the precise cantations required to not getting your question closed, while the OP may not be as fluent in Stack Overflowese and English as the community moderators.

Or, if I missed the memo that Stack Overflow currently only allows questions about debugging code, then please give me the link to it. For the record, with that I am **not** asking for off-site resources.

Comment: Did you consider editing?

Comment: @rene I definitely have, did you consider reading? I'm asking other people to not be too trigger-happy based on some words, but editing out those words instead when the mere presence of said words does not indicate a valid reason to close a question.

Comment: "Please enumerate all possible ways to solve this problem" & "How to do X" mean the same thing. But the issue is indeed "narrow enough context". Questions should be downvoted & closed when people do not research & do not debug & do not try to minimize the problem. The language you mention comes with such too-broad questions. Those words & phrases reflect the author trying to present further effort on answering their own question as beyond their ability & control so they can not try. Editing them out generally leaves a question that should be downvoted & closed. PS "I think"--waffle.

Comment: While there are questions that are incorrectly closed because of the existence of "trigger words", this is far from the norm in my experience. More often than not, those words are a valuable heuristic. If anything, linking to the "opinions" meta question serves to prove that point. When possible, if I find a question that can be salvaged from a too broad/opinion based one into a well-scoped one, I edit it. But many times, that's not what the OP is after.

Comment: I disagree that a question should be *"closed when people do not research"* @philipxy . Downvoted certainly, but a lack of effort in itself is not a reason to vote to close (this doesn't apply to homework questions, but I use a custom close vote for that). There's no "The question shows no research effort" close option. I however, won't bother to answer a question if a user hasn't "bothered" to try, but that doesn't mean others won't.

Comment: @philipxy not at all: *"Questions should be downvoted & closed when people do not research & do not debug & do not try to minimize the problem."* you **very** clearly state there that questions with no research should be closed (and downvoted). There's no ambiguity there.

Comment: @Larnu You are misrepresenting the words you quote. It says "when people do not research & do not debug & do not try to minimize the problem". That's "&" not "or".

Comment: @philipxy again, I am not. You are stating that if any of those requirements are met, the question should be both closed and downvoted, and I strongly disagree with that. If that isn't what you are saying, that the ambiguity is yours, not mine.

Comment: @Larnu I think that philipxy's point is that they  do not they claim _"if **any** of those requirements are met"_, but that _"if **all** of those requirements are met"_. Not saying that you have to agree or not with them, but that maybe they are not claiming what you think they are.

Comment: Are good questions really being closed? Using heuristics/weasel words to identify possible bad questions, then reviewing them manually and casting close votes where appropriate is a good thing imo, but if someone closes only based on these heuristics systematically, we should address that.

Comment: Perhaps, @yivi but, philip offered no alternative wording other than to tell me i "read it wrong", so I could only reaffirm my disaggrement,

Comment: @Larnu In their [last comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402987/how-should-we-handle-weasel-words-or-unintentionally-broad-questions-that-are#comment809105_402987) they further insisted that it's a logical `and` and not a logical `or`, but you reply to that saying they say "if any of those requirements are met". That confuses me a bit.

Comment: I see a point in saying *the OP* did not intend to *ask* a question as broadly, but yet (in my experience) there are many people that intend to *answer* a question as broadly. Sure, editing could remove the triggers for answerers, but is that really an effective use of curator time?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi if we don't lose track of the purpose of this site, namely to answer each and every programming question in an explanative tone with links to references, then I think closing questions because some other people are not that good at writing such answers is kinda missing the point.

Comment: @CodeCaster Seriously asking: If we answer a question properly but no-one gets to see the answer, did we answer the question? Is there a point to "answer each and every programming question in an explanative tone with links to references" when said answers get buried beneath heaps of trash?

Comment: Probably relevant [Please, is anything going to be done about the pedantic question closers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/299394/please-is-anything-going-to-be-done-about-the-pedantic-question-closers). Another problem is that destruction always wins and it's very fast, while getting posts back seems slow and only done one post at a time.

Comment: @Scratte thanks, nice find. Shog seems to agree with my sentiment: _"Whether you like it or not, a tremendous amount of knee-jerk moderation is triggered by plain old bad writing"_. However, editing is not nearly as organized or easy as is closing. I am not lashing out to the closers. Closers are doing a tremendous job at closing questions that shouldn't or couldn't be answered, but they are also closing a not insignificant amount of questions that hold value from the beginning, only if you can look through poor phrasing.

Comment: @CodeCaster What I see in that post is that the Question and the Answer seem to have the same message. But the difference of votes on those is.. interesting. It seems to be a trend that's also settling on your post here :(

Comment: @CodeCaster I must admit I don't care for your personal meta-points :) But I care for the message that it sends, that people do not agree to preserve HowTo posts. Or that it's fine to vote to close on a few triggering words. I (anyone) could become a very prolific debug-my-tictactoe answerer and rise to elevated privileges, but I just don't think those Answers would be very useful to anyone other than asker. I'd rather not we head that way. I'd much rather focus attention answering the other types of posts. So I care for the score of this post, and the other one.

Comment: Well... nice list. There are some truly disagreeable choices in there, in my opinion anyway. Worth a moment of reflection for sure.

Comment: @Gimby sorry for my earlier response which I removed, I appear to have misunderstood you. So to be clear, you agree that at least some of those have been closed with the wrong close reason, or should not be closed at all?

Comment: *What is the best way to create fallback for clamp()? - they're not asking for opinions, they're asking for the way with the most coverage in browser support* - It's unclear to me what's wrong with the 2nd fallback; @media for width has 97% support. I've left a comment on the question but if I'm missing something obvious, let me know. I'm willing to be the 3rd reopen on that one if that gets explained.

Comment: @BSMP sure, that might be an "unclear what you're asking, add more details about what exactly you're looking for", but "the best browser coverage" is not an opinion. It's not like they're asking for other user's favorite libraries or anything. Good on you for commenting that.

Answer (score 11):

Disclaimer: I mostly frequent the [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag. This answer might be biased for ["a madhouse"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/402991/5349916).

---

> If you answer a question and no one reads it, did you answer the question?

An OP asking a proper question with *unintentionally* broad wording is not in itself bad. Experienced people can often find the "hidden" question, either directly or via comments.

The issue is that an unintentionally broad question can be correctly answered without actually answering the hidden question. Especially for simple tasks, there might be half a dozen or more *technically* correct answers before a proper answer arrives.

Yes, in some cases those late answers will be found by the OP, identified as correct versus all the others, and actually help them. In many other cases, in my experience very many cases, they are buried.

When good answers are buried, this is bad *for everybody involved*. The early answerers will not learn that they should change their habits. The late answerers will get no proper impact for their effort. And the OP will not be helped with their issue.

---

Are you frequenting a high-quality, low-frequency tag? Be kind and take the time to help the OP.

Are you frequenting a low-quality, high-frequency tag? Cut the losses and close vote.

Comment: I'm in the latter camp: C#, SQL, ASP.NET. I disagree with the sentiment to throw out the baby with the bath water. Click through a few of the questions I've linked to in my question, especially the new ones. They don't attract low-quality answers, are not off-topic in any way, and should definitely not be closed because _some other questions do or are_.

Comment: @CodeCaster I agree that questions which *will not* attract low-quality answers *should not* be closed. But I also see that questions which *will* attract low-quality answers *should* be closed. Sadly, there is no way to know which is which upfront. There will be some wring decisions either way. If optimistic voting works for you, *frankly that's great and I would like it too*. But I am encountering too many babies that turn their bath water into people stew when given the time.

Comment: The idiocracy here is that those questions are closed _after_ being answered with facts, and not having brewed any baby stew at all. Don't get me wrong, and I repeat this every time I ask or respond to such questions: I am all for closing off-topic questions, and I believe I am in the overall top 50 of gold badge closevoters for duplicate questions. I just loathe good questions with good answers being closed for irrelevant reasons, let alone them being deleted, destroying information, gaining nothing in result.

Comment: It would be nice if high-rep users could have "reopen-hammer" powers commensurate with their "dupe-hammer" powers.  Probably won't fix when a diamond mod gets close-happy, but it would be something.  And would mean folks like @CodeCaster would have options besides throwing them all on the mercy of meta.

Comment: @CodeCaster Again, I agree that some of these cases are really bad. Yes, CV'ing pessimistically means all sorts of collateral damage – like 2 people voting before an answer means one bad vote after an answer is enough to kill it. Point is, I *also* loathe all the good questions not answered because experts are burned out or distracted by crap. I would rather prefer a better way to recover the few good closed questions than to avoid closing the many bad questions. But either way is a means to deal with a situation we should not have in the first place, and there seems to be no optimal solution.

Comment: @CodeCaster, wait, it appears gold badge reopen powers [already exist.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333620/restrict-mj%c3%b6lnir-privilege-when-voting-to-re-open-a-question-that-was-close-vote).  And you have a gold badge in [tag:C#] and [tag:.net],  So you should probably be able to hammer [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64872554/c-sharp-comparing-strings-ignoring-both-whitespaces-cr-etc-and-cases) open at least

Comment: @DanielF The gold badge is only for duplicates. Gold badgers can dupe hammer *and unhammer* duplicates, but nothing else.

Answer (score 10):

Note: I mostly follow [numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numpy), so my answer might reflect more the [culture of that tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52605202/4427777) than others.  I have been known to [dive on the grenade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64908629/what-s-the-best-way-to-iterate-2-arrays-correspondingly-when-using-numpy) for new folks who happen to stumble into the trap of using "weasel words" because they don't even know what what they're asking for is called.  Or don't understand that "best" can mean "most pythonic"or "fastest" or "doesn't require me to buy a new computer" - but sort of get that in a beginner's sense, and generally [appreciate when they get all three answers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64676672/how-can-i-make-a-distance-matrix-with-own-metric-using-no-loop#comment114358237_64676672)

That said, my answer is - **"It depends."**

[numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numpy) is a small tag.  We have some spectacular answerers, and few questions.  We can sort of afford to be lenient and handhold.  We can stop and think and try to decypher broken English and half-formed code, never mind some weaselly language. It helps that many questioners we get are obviously experts in diverse scientific fields, and thus really *get* the need to ask good questions even if they don't know how.

But then I switch to [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), and I see why bright lines are needed.  Why sometimes if a question has both tags, I can barely get a comment or an edit in before the question is closed.

[python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python)'s a madhouse.  And bright lines are a safety mechanism against that.  If you don't want your smart folks to burn out, they need to mentally triage.  And flagging and close-voting is part of that.  As an extreme example, the few times I've wandered into the wreckage of a [numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numpy) question that also tagged [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) it reminded me of boot camp - bewildering, terrifying, rigidly organized, ruthless - and necessary.

Would it be better if bigger tags could be less rigid?  Sure.  But we do the good we can.  They do the good they can. And we sort of have to trust people, and groups, to decide that on their own.

Comment: That said, it can be extremely frustrating when a good question gets kicked to review and the elements of "local culture" (and even the comments explaining why the question is ok in that tag) are lost.  A few downvotes and a flag can [kill a question quickly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64610107/how-to-split-time-data-h-m-s-in-pandas/64611040#comment114243709_64611040) and not leave much opportunity for those who want to to help

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I understand your sentiment, and agree. My point is that some people, when they encounter a question that makes them go _"I don't even know where to begin explaining how wrong you are"_, go for the close button, while the question is in fact not close-worthy. They just appear to go for the lazy option. If that is a result from the amount of new, bad questions we get, then closing some of them with the wrong reason is not the solution.

Comment: Oftentimes one person's "lazy" is another person's "at the end of my rope."

Comment: If people are getting tired of the amount of actual problematic posts and are closing questions that shouldn't be closed as a result, they should stop closing for a while. Just as delivery drivers have mandatory breaks after a certain amount of time, lest they not crash their trucks into innocent traffic.

Comment: @CodeCaster why isn't "*I don't even know where to begin explaining how wrong you are*" too broad? If there is *so much wrong*, it seems like the asker should go through some basic tutorials first. Q&A is not a tutoring service, we shouldn't really deal with the absolute basics. If a person trying to build a full GUI calculator but struggles with `if` and loops, then there isn't *one* issue they have.

Comment: @VLAZ why do you twist my words like that? I am of course talking about a question that is not too broad, that does not deserve closure, but where the OP seems thoroughly misguided, and that an answer has to address those fundamental mistakes. That can be as simple as writing a simple sentence, but the answer _has_ to start with that to make sense to the OP, given their lack of knowledge from this hypothetical text in this hypothetical question. Nowhere am I suggesting that we should start private tutoring in answers.

Comment: @CodeCaster "*I am of course talking about a question that is not too broad, that does not deserve closure*" I quoted yo and the reasoning I quoted didn't sound like something that doesn't deserve closure. If you "of course" meant something different, then you should have chosen different wording because *to me* an "*I don't even know where to begin explaining how wrong you are*" is when the OP shows clear lack of knowledge of the fundamentals. A single fundamental mistake is fine. Although we also have an entire close reason for that.

Comment: @VLAZ that is because it's a comment. For my general stance on the subject and context of said comment, read the question; I am the OP. You're also very wrong; the "lacks minimal understanding" close reason was eradicated years ago.

Comment: @CodeCaster The "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo" is still around and applicable in many cases when OP has made a simple fundamental error. If they didn't initialise a variable and then get the wrong result many lines later, for example, or they have an off by one error of some sort.

Comment: @VLAZ read the room, or in this case, the question. I am talking about questions that are not typos, not too broad, not asking for off-site resources (should I continue to list all valid close reasons?), but questions that should stay open, **but** contain words like "the best way", just because the OP is clueless or lacks experience, which are incorrectly closed just based on the presence of those words. Do you get it now? We don't close questions just because the OP doesn't know something that we do or find obvious. If a question makes you go "Gah, _really_?", don't close, just move away.

Comment: @CodeCaster I'm trying to impress on you that what you *think* should stay open may not actually need to stay open. Otherwise why discuss this at all? It's a tautology - "everything that should stay open should stay open because it is supposed to stay open". Sure, I completely agree with this. No way to disagree. But it's also not very *useful* thing to claim. Yet if you *think* some people are closing because there are many things wrong with a post then perhaps it's not a question that *should* stay open.

Comment: @VLAZ I find no proof anywhere that for example the questions I linked in my question here should be closed for any known reason. Just because readers find something silly, or laughably stupid, or hopelessly clueless, does not mean a question should be closed, let alone deleted. If someone doesn't have the patience to explain something thoroughly (which, again, I feel like I need to repeat given this conversation so far, can happen in a single sentence, so is not by definition a too broad question), they should not vote to close just because of that. Someone else will come along and explain.

Comment: @CodeCaster stop trying to move away from what I'm talking about. Yet again, it's about the literal quote from you "*I don't even know where to begin explaining how wrong you are*". Not about the examples in the OP - that one quote that I've already had to remind you was what I was talking about. I'm still talking about that one. The reasoning you used there suggests you may want more questions open than necessary. Because *if* somebody were to use that reasoning, then perhaps a question really close worthy. Yet you claim that is *always* wrong and should *never* be a justification for closing

Comment: @VLAZ you're the one moving the goalposts with each response. I am talking about questions with which nothing is wrong, apart from the OP showing that they're clueless about what they are trying to accomplish. That in itself is not a reason to close a question, period. Yet that is what I see happening often enough, and I blame frustration or tiredness on the reviewer's part there. There is nothing else wrong about the hypothetical question I'm talking about, you keep adding or suggesting that.

Comment: @CodeCaster you keep saying "Ignore what I said and just assume I'm right" But I don't agree. Given the reasoning I saw, I think you may be trying to dismiss legitimate close votes. I've been saying this throughout our entire interaction here. And yet you keep trying to tell me to shut up and accept you're right by shifting back to the examples in the question. Are there posts closed that shouldn't have been? Yes, there are. Should *no* post ever be closed? No, that's not true. I see repeat dismissal of reasonable concerns from you. To suggest that you're unquestionably right isn't reassuring.

Comment: I would have assumed that almost all Numpy questions are also tagged either Python or C. Isn't that so?

Answer (score 7):

> So can we please take a step back, and not jump straight to the close button when we read the words "any way", "opinion", "best practice", and so on, but perhaps help the (usually not natively English speaking) OP by merely editing out such terms that may make a question seem to have not enough focus?

Yes. Thank you for the suggestion. I'll do that. I know that keywords alone do not define the quality of a question or answer (otherwise we would all be replaced by some tensorflow instance by tomorrow). I try to really only vote to close for those questions that deserve it and sometimes also comment before if I see a chance to salvage the question, but it always pays off to be conscious about inherent biases.

If you want more systematic research could be done to find out which specific kind of questions most often get wrongfully closed.

Editing is also a good idea and I strongly recommend it if there is time.

However, as a last item, I would like to emphasize that also the asker has a duty to ask the best possible (clearest, best worded, ..) question. It's obviously a skill that can be improved by studying other successful questions, reading documentation and taking time as well as paying attention to comments. Nobody is perfect and to err is human, but I would like to see the will of askers to really ask good questions. In these cases I'd be more than happy to polish them even further.